# Grails - Fatal error during compilation org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm developing a Grails 2.4.4 plugin. I added the following dependencies to the plugin BuildConfig file:

```
String springSocialVersion = "1.1.0.RELEASE"
String springSecurityVersion = '3.2.7.RELEASE'

compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:${springSocialVersion}") {
    excludes "spring-aop", "spring-beans", "spring-context", "spring-core",
            "spring-expression", "spring-web", "spring-webmvc"
}

compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:$springSecurityVersion"

compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2")

compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1"
```

The problem is when I add the plugin as a compile-time dependency in my app, I get the following exception:

> Fatal error during compilation org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/Users/jeff/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails/grails-core/jars/grails-core-2.2.3.jar!/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/DirectoryWatcher$FileChangeListener.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)

If I remove the dependencies from the plugin and add them directly to the BuildConfig in the app everything works fine

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you have to first figure out why `grails-core-2.2.3.jar` is referred at the first place. clear ivy-cache. 2.4.4 would not refer to ivy-cache by default, because the default strategy is `aether`.

Comment: I was using the wrong version of spring-social-core.